# Closed surface embedded in $\mathbb R^3$ with nonnegative Gaussian curvature at countable number of points

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

This is a closely related question:

[Existence of closed surface having only negative gaussian curvature.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1818437/existence-of-closed-surface-having-only-negative-gaussian-curvature)

The answer is that such surface ($2$-D manifold) does not exist if we require it to be embedded to $\mathbb R^3$.

However I am still wondering whether there are closed $2$-D manifolds embedded in $\mathbb R^3$ with only countable number of points where the curvature is nonnegative and if it doesn't exist, why?

I am specializing in theoretical chemistry and am a math hobbyist so please feel free to point it out if there is any misunderstanding or any blatant error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: By closed surface do you mean a (smooth) compact surface without boundary? If so, it must have uncountably many points of positive curvature.

Comment: Once you know the curvature is positive at a point, continuity of the curvature tells you it's positive in a small disc around that point, which contains an uncountable number of points.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis I see. Sorry I have failed to see that. Thank you very much for enlightening me.